# Append to the same text file in c#

Tags: multithreading, file, text, concurrency, append

I need to append to a text file with the same code running in multiple instances. In the try block I open the file, write one record and close.

```
        lfilExceptionLogFileStream = new FileStream(istrExceptionInfoFullFileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write);
        lfilExceptionLog = new StreamWriter(lfilExceptionLogFileStream);
```

Should there be an issue, in the catch block I pause for 1 sec `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);` and call the same function. I retry 99 times.

With `FileShare.Write` when I test concurrently 3 times - data is lost. `FileShare.None` - locks the file for a long time

I have tried quite a bit. If there is an easy way to find if the file is locked I can wait until it is locked. I have tried using the lock object - no luck

Appreciate if somebody can provide a workable solution.

Ravi

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution is to:

1. Create StreamWriter in the beginning
2. Create synchronized version StreamWriter.Synchronized(lfilExceptionLog)
3. Pass synchronized instance to all threads and use it to log stuff.
4. Close StreamWriter when done.

Comment: I changed to StreamWriter.Synchronized - I still need to use the retry logic. I have a Console Application which calls this DLL. I execute the same EXE from multiple windows

Comment: Thanks Sergey
1. Added retry logic
2. Executed console application from 4 windows
3. Each window called the method 100,000 times
This worked fine.
I am only worried if the retry exceeds the limit of 99 I will not be capturing everything
I am displaying the retry on the console and all windows had retries
If this does not make sense please let me know

Comment: I think retries are wrong way of doing this. I think either every executable shall write to its own file and then you combine them in the end, or you use some interprocess synchronization, like Mutex http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx